# Conversion from MFC CImage to Opencv IPlImage

Tags: c++, user-interface, opencv, mfc

I am having a camera application using opencv where I am using MFC GUI.I need to convert the CImage to IplImage for the Opencv modules for image processing and convert it back to CImage for displaying in the window again.

I researched in this topic but not enough examples and solutions.Anybody have some suggestions.Thanks

This is my code...

```
void CChildView::OnFileOpenimage(void)
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CString strFilter;
    CSimpleArray<GUID> aguidFileTypes;
    HRESULT hResult;
hResult = imgOriginal.GetExporterFilterString(strFilter,aguidFileTypes);
if (FAILED(hResult)) {
    CString fmt;
    fmt.Format("GetExporterFilter failed:\n%x - %s", hResult, _com_error(hResult).ErrorMessage());
    ::AfxMessageBox(fmt);
    return;
}

CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, strFilter);
dlg.m_ofn.nFilterIndex = m_nFilterLoad;
hResult = (int)dlg.DoModal();
if(FAILED(hResult)) {
    return;
}

m_nFilterLoad = dlg.m_ofn.nFilterIndex;
imgOriginal.Destroy();
CString pathval =  dlg.GetPathName();
hResult = imgOriginal.Load(dlg.GetPathName());
if (FAILED(hResult)) {
    CString fmt;
    fmt.Format("Load image failed:\n%x - %s", hResult, _com_error(hResult).ErrorMessage());
    ::AfxMessageBox(fmt);
    return;
}
// IplImage *img from  imgOriginal; want to convert here for further processing.

m_nImageSize = SIZE_ORIGINAL;
Invalidate();
UpdateWindow();

}
```

Comment: did you had a look at the CImage class definition? Did you had a look at the IplImage structure definition? Do you see some patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem for quite a while myself.  I found this code [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/33709) which I ended up using that worked quite well.  Instead of researching "CImage to IplImage" you should search "HBITMAP to IplImage"

```
IplImage* hBitmap2Ipl(HBITMAP hBmp, bool flip)
{
    BITMAP bmp;
    ::GetObject(hBmp,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmp);

    int    nChannels = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? 1 : bmp.bmBitsPixel/8;
    int    depth     = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? IPL_DEPTH_1U : IPL_DEPTH_8U;

    IplImage *img=cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight), depth, nChannels);

    img->imageData = (char*)malloc(bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*nChannels*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(img->imageData,(char*)(bmp.bmBits),bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*nChannels);
    return img;
```

}

Usage:

```
ATL::CImage image;
//whatever code you use to generate the image goes here
IplImage *convertedImage=hBitmap2Ipl(image.Detach());
image.Destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched half the night for my copy-and-paste memory leak and finally found it!

So here is an **updated** code snippet of the original answer. The important thing for me was to use *cvCreateImage* instead of *cvCreateImageHeader* because I did use *cvReleaseImage* after the call to *hBitmap2IplImage*. Also flipping was neccessary in my case. Cheers!

```
IplImage* hBitmap2IplImage(HBITMAP hBmp, bool flip)
{
    BITMAP bmp;
    ::GetObject(hBmp,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmp);

    int    nChannels = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? 1 : bmp.bmBitsPixel/8;
    int    depth     = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? IPL_DEPTH_1U : IPL_DEPTH_8U;

    IplImage *img=cvCreateImage(cvSize(bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight), depth, nChannels);

    size_t imgSize = bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*nChannels;
    memcpy_s(img->imageData, imgSize, (char*)(bmp.bmBits), imgSize);
    if (flip)
        cvFlip(img, NULL, 0);

    return img;
}
```

Usage:

```
ATL::CImage image;
HBITMAP hBitmap = image.Detach(); // some handle to your bitmap
bool flip = true;
IplImage* pSomeIplImage = hBitmap2IplImage(hBitmap, flip);
image.Destroy();
//
// use "pSomeIplImage"
//
cvReleaseImage( &pSomeIplImage ); // don't forget
```

Answer (score -1):

If a bitmap image is on a view you can use the device context(CDC dcBuffer ) to copy it.

```
IplImage *pCapture = cvCreateImage(cvSize(U16_IMAGE_WIDTH/2,U16_IMAGE_HEIGHT/2),8, 3);

::GetDIBits(dcBuffer.GetSafeHdc(), bitmapBuffer, 0, U16_IMAGE_HEIGHT/2, pCapture->imageData, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

cvSaveImage("temp.bmp", pCapture);

cvReleaseImage(&pCapture);
```